# Custom view ClassNotFoundException from LayoutInflater

Tags: android, proguard, android-custom-view

On one of our release builds, we use [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard) where it helps obfuscate and minimize the code. This issue is not reproducable on my device or an emulator, but from some users via Crashlytics we get an exception that says the system could not find the class. The exception comes from various devices and above Android Lollipop. (API 21)

Exception trace:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Did not find class "com.example.android.views.CustomImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass + 56(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 511(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 469(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView + 583(LayoutInflater.java:583)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 764(LayoutInflater.java:764)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 704(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 835(LayoutInflater.java:835)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren + 798(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 838(LayoutInflater.java:838)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren + 798(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 838(LayoutInflater.java:838)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren + 798(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 515(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 423(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at com.example.android.fragments.MyFragment.onCreateView + 160(AdPopupFragmentVertical.java:160)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView + 2600(Fragment.java:2600)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 881(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1238(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1303(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange + 2659(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated + 2613(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated + 246(FragmentController.java:246)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart + 542(FragmentActivity.java:542)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart + 201(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
```

Related ProGuard rule:

`-keep class com.example.android.views.** { *; }`

And, to go even safer, I added the `@Keep` annotation to the top of the class aswell, like this:

```
package com.example.android.views;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
     // rest of the code
}
```

To make sure, I built a release APK and inspected with APK Analyzer. Now, the application uses MultiDex (because it has to, it contains ads) and the `classes.dex` file seems to contain the view with its correct name, path (I mean package) and methods. So, I don't understand why some devices are failing to find this view.

What else can be done to resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: If it helps, this view is a special view that creates a drop shadow depending on the bitmap that it is sent to, using Renderscript, above Android Lollipop. (API 21)

Edit 2: Here is my app-level build.gradle file. (skipped unnecessary parts)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' // this is ignored already
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1000
        versionName "1000"
        multiDexEnabled true
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        def name = flavor.getVersionName()

        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable())
            name += 'd'
        else
            name += 'r'

        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionNameOverride = name
        }

        variant.outputs.all {
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            versionName += variant.buildType.isDebuggable() ? 'd' : 'r'
            outputFileName = "example-${versionName}.apk"
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```